# Unable to access Docker NGINX on 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nginx, docker, tcp-ip

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

```
> docker-version
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
```

I run:

```
> docker run --name my-nginx-1 -P -d nginx
> docker port my-nginx-1
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32770
> wget 0.0.0.0:32770
--2018-07-30 05:29:38--  http://0.0.0.0:32770/
Connecting to 0.0.0.0:32770... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

It never gets the response. If I run this on OSX, a 200 OK is returned.

```
sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
```

Does not show a process listening on port 32770. I was seeing a ':::32770' entry indicating that docker was affecting ipv6 but, based on https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2174, I added the following to /etc/default/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1
```

but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Your commands work for me on 16.04 (same  docker version) and I have also only tcp6 entry. Maybe try with `wget localhost:32770` ?

Comment: Unfortunately it produces the same result. Not a blocker, in any case. Thanks.

Comment: Just an FYI.. the standard `docker run hello-world` works fine. I suspected an iptables issue so installed ufw. The gufw utility shows default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the VPN client - it was re-routing requests even when they referred to the localhost. Stopping the VPN solves the problem.